# UnitTest++ creates cmd windows, which can't be closed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unittest++

I have a setup for using UnitTest++ like [this](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/money_tutorial/) in VS2008.

Sometimes the cmd window, which shows the console output of the unit tests just hangs.

I can move the window, resize and stuff, but I'm unable to close it. I see the window in the App tab of the Task Manager, but not in the Process tab, "Switch to process" doesn't work either.
Stop debugging or closing VS is also no help, it seems VS has lost control over this window.

If this cmd window is lost, I'm unable to shutdown my computer, which is pretty annoying

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Unkillable console windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506256/unkillable-console-windows)